# Limit the displayed table rows - create multiple "table-pages" with a menu under the table to access

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, tabular

I have a table with many rows, which gets populated with data from a database.

I want to only display around 20 at a time.

It would be good if there are numbers under the table, with which I can access the other "table-pages".

I know this is possible, but I just can't seem to find it online.

It should look like this:

[image: https://gyazo.com/3b84ed5f00be2780e4266d53e9eec2ba]

I just seem to not find the right word, for what I am looking for, I think.

Comment: What you are looking for is called "paging".

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Client-side-HTML-Table-Pagination-Plugin-with-jQuery-Paging.html

using this script is a easy and fast way to deal with paging!